# Apache to Nginx Conversion Issue with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to migrate a Apache website into fully Nginx powered with PHP-FPM.

However when i try to convert following complicated rules set on the .htaccess file for Apache all my attempts with Online converters failed with errors.

Is there any one who can help me with this ?

```
#ModPagespeed on
Options -indexes
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
# BEGIN Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L,NE]
## replace of space with -
# executes **repeatedly** as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE]
# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" /$1-$2? [L,R=302,NE]


RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)$ index.php?search=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?layout=article&id=$1

RewriteRule ^adwords/([^/]+)$ adwords/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ images/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ images/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ajax/([^/]+)$ ajax/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)$ info/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^reports/([^/]+)$ reports/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^css/([^/]+)$ css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ css/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^includes/([^/]+)$ includes/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^includes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ includes/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^reports/([^/]+)$ reports/$1 [QSA,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?search=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Rewrite
```

If i convert this with below converter i get error 
http://www.anilcetin.com/

```
Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] invalid variable name in /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:12 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Post yout nginx config please. What does the error log say?

Comment: it runs with plesk, wht vars on nginx config has effect on this ? as i thought every nginx is same when it comes to url rewrite isn't it ?